# Is there a good, simple Python charting library with no dependencies?

Tags: python-2.7, graph, charts, plot

I'm writing an open-source project which is not primarily graphics-oriented. It would be handy to provide some very basic line graphs (as a way of letting users look at their data), but not at the cost of adding further dependencies (my user base will probably include novice programmers, so I want to make their lives as simple as possible). Are there graphing/plotting /charting libraries out there which are simple, lightweight, and have no additional dependencies? The only thing I've found is the Python wrapper for the Google Chart API -- which would be great, except that it will only handle a very small amount of data, even with the 'simple' encoding.

It's definitely ideal if the solution is pip-installable; I can't make the project entirely free of dependencies, but I'd at least like users to be able to just do 'pip install -r requirements.txt' and be done with it. That's one thing that's steered me away from matplotlib -- on some systems, at least, there's trickiness with the dependencies there, because numpy has to be installed first. So second-best, for me, would be a library with some dependencies which are themselves pip-installable.

Searching on SO and on the [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting), I find lots of stuff which is out of date and unsupported, lots of stuff that tries to be simple but does so by depending on much heavier-weight libraries, and/or has dependencies that can't be installed with pip, or don't play well with virtualenv. I want to give my users something that comes as close to running out-of-the-box as I can get it. There must be *something* out there that's a good fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [pygal](http://pygal.org). Only one dependency on lxml.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [PlainChart](https://github.com/gduverger/plainchart), a no-dependencies, `pip`-installable, plain-text charting utility in Python (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by dependencies.  Matplotlib  http://matplotlib.org/ is a good plotting package for python but has some dependencies that may or may not meet your requirements.